# is there a way to communicate testcafe with my local server?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have been trying testcafe and I would like to emulate this behavior:

1- launch testcafe from a local script(easy part, no problem)

2- Post instructions to testcafe server (Posting to Proxy Serv? using BrowserProvider API?)

3- get a response from the posted instructions

Scripting tests for testcafe is fairly easy using the common examples and tutorials, but the expected behavior for this particular case is **triggering the instructions** in real time. I am kind of lost in this one and the Documentation is kind of confusing with the Advanced Tutorials.

I would like to know options or actual implementations of the problem

Answer (score 1):

Testcafe does not have REPL. I suggest you take a look at [Testcafe live mode](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/run-tests.html#live-mode), which can be helpful.